# Primefaces DataTable reset page numbers

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, pagination

I am using Prime Faces 4.0 and have a DataTable with lazyloading and pagination. Everything works fine except for one thing. When a user has made a search and i.e. moves the datatable to page 3, a new search after it will start at page 3 (however the data is correctly displayed from page 1). Its only the numbers of the paginator that wont reset.

Ive searched and found that there is a fix in adding
          `onclick="myWidgetVar.getPaginator().setPage(0);"`         to the search button. However, this will reset the pagination for all open tabs in my TabView. Obviously I dont want this behaviour.

Is there anything I can do so that the page numbers are resetted and displayed correctly when a user makes a new search in PF 4.0, or even in 5?

Comment: How about resetting the entire table? `DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("my_form_id:my_table_id"); dataTable.reset();`

Comment: What do you mean with: "However, this will reset the pagination for all open tabs." This shouldn't happen because javascript variables (the widgetvar is one yes) that live in other browser tabs won't be invoked. The proposed fix you are showing is working, I used it plenty of times myself. Please provide some more information about your setup.

Comment: @ChristopherS Sorry for being unclear. I dont mean browser tabs, I mean tabs as tabView tabs.

Comment: Did you try `onclick="PF('myWidgetVar').getPaginator().setPage(0);"`?

Comment: @ChristopherS Just tried it and unfortunately it has the same behaviour. Resets all open tabs in TabView.

Comment: @Daniel I am trying your solution but I cant get it to do anything. Basically I find my DataTable component and do a reset but nothing in particular happens. I also tried dataTable.setFirst(0) as suggested somewhere on the PF forum, but nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: @Daniel , make sure you update your datatable after the reset, showing your code might raise the chances to get a better help...

Comment: @Daniel This should do it I think: `onclick="#{p:widgetVar('myWidgetVar')}.getPaginator().setPage(0);"`